# how to use mod_rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello i want to rewrite the following link:

```
http://websoftit.ro/social/profil.php?user=Ancuta Mirela
```

to `http://websoftit.ro/social/Ancuta Mirela`. 
Can someone tell me how to do that with mod_rewrite also maybe give me a link to a good documentation to learn myself how to do that?
Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+social/profil\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /social/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^social/([^/]+)/?$ /social/profil.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I would suggest http://askapache.com as a good reference for learning `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: hehe thnx a lot, it's actualy working with your method, i rly don't know from where you get those [^/+ or what they mean but it's working, i hope i'm gna learn from that link to write my own rules :D

Comment: but still, if i want to add a parameter like ID to get it with $_GET is it posible? if i rewrite the url

Comment: Yes using same pattern you can use any parameter. Let me know if you run into any issues and I will assist you.

Comment: i dont manage to make it working, seems mod_rewrite beats me:). I want `http://websoftit.ro/social/profil.php?user=Ancuta Mirela&categ=1` to rewrite to `http://websoftit.ro/social/Ancuta Mirela` but still i want to $_GET the `categ` value

Comment: You cannot omit the `categ` value in redirected URL. It has be there to be able to rewrite internally. Something like `/social/Ancuta Mirela/1` will work

Comment: oh i understand, thnx:)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^social/([^/]+)$ social/profil.php?user=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)user=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://websoftit.ro/social/%1 [NE,R=301,L]
```